# JSF XHTML automatic static code review and quality measurement

Tags: jsf

Does anyone of you know any code reviewing tool designed for JSF like PMD/Checkstyle and other for Java? I am searching for a way to check some good practices on facelet pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I didn't found such a tool yet.

The best I found for the moment is a [web plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Web+Plugin) for the [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) tool, but it does not provide a lot of (useful) information. However, I think it's a good idea to keep an eye on it!

Comment: Will test it and give you my feedback.